# Automatic pagination in vue and vuetify

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

I have a pagination made in vuetify, I need it to be automatic, that is to say that it changes the page automatically and when it reaches the last page it returns to the first, is there any way to control it by events or a way in which this can be manipulated, thank you any guides or resources you can share.

```
 <!-- Pagination -->
  <v-row>
    <div class="text-center">
        <v-pagination v-model="page" :length="numbersPage"></v-pagination>
    </div>
  </v-row>
```

Comment: the [documentation](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-pagination/#props) is always a great place to start to see what you can do.  I'll say your v-model is the page that will be displayed, so just change `page` value to the next, first, last page, etc. based on your requirements.  if there's something more specific you're having trouble with please provide more details.

Comment: How can I do to control that, I was reviewing the documentation but I did not find any event that helps me for this